# Spawn SDF and control joints

Tags: control, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have an SDF file of a robot, and would like to be able to control it's joints in the same way as shown in the tutorial [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control).

The reason why I need this is that I need gearbox joints in my model, like in the example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/4803794276719e7711d7c59a345ed3f3c52bc575/demo_joint_types/model.sdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#model.sdf-157), but they cannot be parsed in URDF. On the other hand, I also need to able to control joint torques, which seems like it cannot work in SDF.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16365/spawn-sdf-and-control-joints/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 40 on 2017-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So while digging through the source code, I found that the robotParam is parsed for the transmissions. That is also mentioned in the tutorial above, but somehow I missed it. So the solution is to provide the URDF location to the robotParam of controller plugin and the transmissions will be parsed from the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) with karma: 40 on 2017-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0